# Canon EOS 400D - Shutter Release Lock Override

Tags: autofocus, troubleshooting, shutter-release, canon-400d

I recently acquired my first DSLR camera, an old *Canon EOS 400D*.

Not the most intuitive device, but for the most part it seems like a fine camera for an amateur.

The problem I have is one of missed opportunity. That being a beginner, still learning to balance the various settings, I will often find myself in difficult, time-sensitive situations where the shutter release refuses to cooperate.

There may be low light, bad focus, poor composition, incorrect ISO, and so on. But while I'm still tweaking the settings and composing my shot, something spontaneous and unexpected will happen and my priority goes from capturing a perfect image, to just being able to quickly snap whatever I can.

Is there a way that I can deactivate or override this feature that prevents less-than-ideal shots from being taken?

[image: Canon EOS 400D]
[image: Canon EOS 400D]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most users, the vast majority of the time the issue is focus confirmation. Turning autofocus off by sliding the *AF/M* switch on the lens from *AF* to *M* will allow the shutter to release without AF confirmation. Of course you will need to focus the lens yourself by turning the focus ring on the lens. If you have *One Shot* AF mode selected the focus confirmation light in the lower right hand corner of the viewfinder will continue to indicate when the lens is focused on the selected AF point(s).

If you don't have a copy of the *EOS 400D Instruction Manual* you can view or download it in .pdf format from [here](http://www.camera-usermanual.com/manuals/canon/Canon_EOS_400D.pdf).

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I haven't tried it yet, but I think this will do the trick.